Forward-Regulator Feedback
I used this circuit diagram section from TI documents and this is feedback for a PoE controller in forward topology and I read somewhere that resistor R18=50ohm is used to have Bode-plot of circuit. Then I would like to know what R18 has to do with Bode-plot, and how can I get it?


Meysam - Hi, Where exactly did the image come from? You mentioned it came from "TI documents", but to comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. || If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + PDF title + its URL). TY (It doesn't apply here, but if the source is offline (e.g. book etc.) please see the linked rule for what should be provided.)

https://www.rohde-schwarz.com/us/applications/power-supply-control-loop-response-measurements-bode-plot-application-card_56279-603776.html
